# How can I fix this Python (py2app) code signing problem

Tags: macos, code-signing, py2app

Before I spend the money for an Apple Developer license I was trying to develop a script to sign my py2app code.  I created a self-signed certificate as per the Apple guidelines.   When I sign the Python framework itself the program stops executing.

```
export APP="PyGitIssueClone.app"
codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "${IDENTITY}" "${APP}/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python"
```

The error I get is:

*not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary*

Signing the libraries as follows w/o the above allows to app to correctly execute:

```
find "PyGitIssueClone.app" -iname '*.so' -or -iname '*.dylib' |
    while read libfile; do
        codesign --sign "${IDENTITY}" "${libfile}" --options=runtime --verbose   >> CodeSigning.log 2>&1 ;
    done;

codesign --sign "${IDENTITY}" --options=runtime "${APP}/Contents/MacOS/python"
codesign --sign "${IDENTITY}" --options=runtime "${APP}/Contents/MacOS/PyGitIssueClone"
```

But obviously the entire app is no longer code signed.  Anyone know how to fix the above error?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apple’s Xcode developer environment developing and publishing code signed applications appears to be largely handled by that tool chain.  To Apple’s credit they have various technical papers scattered around the developer help pages that with serious study you can glean the required information to code sign your non Apple/Swift applications.  Be aware you will have to pay a developer fee for this privilege.  The piper must be paid.  Resistance is futile.

Ok, I wrote a whole article on this.  See my post at:

https://hsanchezii.wordpress.com/2021/10/06/code-signing-python-py2app-applications/